# remove multiple strings from a line with

Tags: awk

I have text file `bnglr.txt` which has following txt, where i want to remove certain strings as per my requirement, indeed i need to remove `| SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) #` <- part from the every line

```
# cat bnglr.txt
rraka-ged.rraka.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) # Profile host: trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) # Profile host: trdls.rraka.com
```

> I have achieved this with `awk` and `tr` which returns the required, 
>   though i'm looking if this can be accomplished with `awk` itself
>   without `tr`.. below is the result output what i received & desired

```
# awk '{gsub( /SUCCESS|rc=0|stdout/, "") ;a=$1;gsub($1 , "");print a,$0 }' bnglr.txt | tr -d "()|" | column -t 
rraka-ged.rraka.com          #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com     #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
```

> Just edited the code ....

```
# awk '{print $1,$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF}' bnglr.txt | column -t
    rraka-ged.rraka.com          Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
    rraka-avinashj.rraka.com     Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com

# awk '{print $1" ", substr($0,index($0,$9))}' bnglr.txt |column -t
    rraka-ged.rraka.com          Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
    rraka-avinashj.rraka.com     Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
```

I'm open to see any solution even if with shell/awk or python..

Comment: What is the expected output? Please add it in your post in code tags and let us know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 .. the last awk liner is working perfect but her ei am using awk & tr both i m looking if this can be clubbed int o `awk` only

Comment: please check my answer now on same.

Comment: You can use your own proposal like this:
awk -F'[ #]' '{print $1,$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF}' OFS=" # " file
And if you do not want to keep the number sign just skip OFS.

Answer (score 3):

characters like `|` and `()` are meta-characters in ERE, so you need to escape them using backslashes to make them behave like ordinary characters

for given example, you can use `sed` instead which uses BRE by default and `|()` are not special

See also [regex differences between different tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

```
$ sed 's/ | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout)//' ip.txt | column -t
rraka-ged.rraka.com       #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com  #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
```

For generic case, I'd suggest [perl Quoting metacharacters](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters)

```
$ # BRE metacharacters have to be taken care
$ echo '1a.c xabcy 2atc3' | sed 's/a.c//g'
1 xy 23
$ echo '1a.c xabcy 2atc3' | sed 's/a\.c//g'
1 xabcy 2atc3
$ # perl has \Q..\E feature to do that automatically
$ echo '1a.c xabcy 2atc3' | perl -pe 's/\Qa.c//g'
1 xabcy 2atc3

$ # but some characters are still special
$ echo '123a/b$c5467' | perl -pe 's|\Qa/b$c||'
123$c5467
$ # so, most robust solution is to pass the string as env string
$ echo '123a/b$c5467' | s='a/b$c' perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{s}//'
1235467
```

Comment: Nice note on perl  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Very often, the files we process contain an inherent pattern that we can exploit. In your case you wish to remove anything between the first `|` and `#`. This is typically a `sed` job

```
sed 's/|[^#]*//' casefile_48275106 | column -t
rraka-ged.rraka.com       #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com  #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
```

The `column -t` takes care of the formatted display.
Hope this helps <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question how to remove the `tr` command's portion from OP's command, following `awk` solution may help you in same.

```
awk '{gsub( /SUCCESS|rc=0|stdout/, "") ;a=$1;gsub($1 , "");gsub(/\||\)|\(/,"");print a,$0 }'  Input_file | column -t
```

***EDIT:*** Or in case you want to make it more simple following may help you in same where you could achieve your output by simple field's printing too.

```
awk '{print $1,$(NF-3),$NF}' Input_file  | column -t
```

Comment: I have added more granuality to awk code..
`# awk '{print $1,$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF}' bnglr.txt | column -t`

Answer (score 1):

***Input***

```
$ cat infile
rraka-ged.rraka.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) # Profile host: trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) # Profile host: trdls.rraka.com
```

**Using awk**

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\|[^#]*/,"")}1' infile | column -t
rraka-ged.rraka.com       #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com  #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com

# OR copy first field and then remove rest all till awk finds #
$ awk '{h=$1; gsub(/^[^#]*/,""); print h,$0}' infile | column -t
rraka-ged.rraka.com       #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com  #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com

# find char # and extract string using substr
$ awk '{print $1, substr($0, index($0,"#"))}'  infile | column -t
rraka-ged.rraka.com       #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com  #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
```

**Using GNU awk**

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/^([^|]*).*(#.*)/,"\\1 \\2","")}' infile | column -t
rraka-ged.rraka.com       #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
rraka-avinashj.rraka.com  #  Profile  host:  trdls.rraka.com
```